# What is thread contention?

Tags: multithreading, language-agnostic

Can someone please explain simply what thread contention is?

I have googled it, but cannot seem to find a simple explanation.

Comment: So write out what your vague thought is on it, so we can see where you may be off, or your understanding may be correct.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Essentially thread contention is a condition where one thread is waiting for a lock/object that is currently being held by another thread. Therefore, this waiting thread cannot use that object until the other thread has unlocked that particular object.

Comment: This answer is incomplete (as are most of the others). While a lock is one type of thing that there can be contention over, it is far from the only such thing. There can be contention for lockless resources as well. (For example, if two threads keep atomically incrementing the same integer, they may experience contention due to cache ping-ponging. No locks are involved.)

Comment: In the case of a Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) such as in CPython, where a thread must always acquire the GIL, multiple threads running in the same process are therefore in contention by default.

Comment: I think you have explained it in terms of Deadlock but it is very much different from the Deadlock.

Answer (score 254):

Several answers seem to focus on lock contention, but locks are not the only resources on which contention can be experienced. Contention is simply when two threads try to access either the same resource or related resources in such a way that at least one of the contending threads runs more slowly than it would if the other thread(s) were not running.

The most obvious example of contention is on a lock. If thread A has a lock and thread B wants to acquire that same lock, thread B will have to wait until thread A releases the lock.

Now, this is platform-specific, but the thread may experience slowdowns even if it never has to wait for the other thread to release the lock! This is because a lock protects some kind of data, and the data itself will often be contended as well.

For example, consider a thread that acquires a lock, modifies an object, then releases the lock and does some other things. If two threads are doing this, even if they never fight for the lock, the threads may run much slower than they would if only one thread was running.

Why? Say each thread is running on its own core on a modern x86 CPU and the cores don't share an L2 cache. With just one thread, the object may remain in the L2 cache most of the time. With both threads running, each time one thread modifies the object, the other thread will find the data is not in its L2 cache because the other CPU invalidated the cache line. On a Pentium D, for example, this will cause the code to run at FSB speed, which is much less than L2 cache speed.

Since contention can occur even if the lock doesn't itself get contended for, contention can also occur when there is no lock. For example, say your CPU supports an atomic increment of a 32-bit variable. If one thread keeps incrementing and decrementing a variable, the variable will be hot in the cache much of the time. If two threads do it, their caches will contend for ownership of the memory holding that variable, and many accesses will be slower as the cache coherency protocol operates to secure each core ownership of the cache line.

Ironically, locks typically *reduce* contention. Why? Because without a lock, two threads could operate on the same object or collection and cause lots of contention (for example, there are lock free queues). Locks will tend to deschedule contending threads, allowing non-contending threads to run instead. If thread A holds a lock and thread B wants that same lock, the implementation can run thread C instead. If thread C doesn't need that lock, then future contention between threads A and B can be avoided for awhile. (Of course, this assumes there are other threads that could run. It won't help if the only way the system as a whole can make useful progress is by running threads that contend.)

Comment: +1  Also, just to make this explicit, the two variables that two cores are fighting over don't even need to be the same variable to cause contention, they only have to be stored in memory in the same cache line.  Padding structures and/or aligning structures to memory can help avoid this form of contention.

Comment: @David please help to understand the last para of your answer in more detail

Comment: @Naroji Ask a question about it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, Are you a C programmer?

Comment: @Pacerier C++ mostly.

Comment: I recently encountered a similar issue. where these two threads are contending for a a hypergraph data structure object whose access is locked by a global static recursive mutex M. there were two function foo() and bar() which were accessing the object being called from two different threads T1 and T2. I saw bar ( called inside T2) was always waiting for foo (called from T1) to release M which often took minutes to happen. Surprisingly, I added a nano second sleep right next to foo call inside the thread calling it and the whole thing became super fast. Why did this happen?  @DavidSchwartz

Comment: @Misgevolution That's very unusual. I can't really thing of an obvious explanation. Do you know why it took so long to release the mutex? What was the thread that held the mutex doing?

Comment: I am not really sure. I might have simplified the scenario a bit so the actual thing is that there are couple of other threads handling telnet connections and one handling some guile input via telnet. So in my previous explanation, T2 was a guile thread waiting to evaluate its input ( A create Hypergraph query) where T1 was a C++ thread (doing read query on the hypergraph object). There also a couple of addtional ephemeral guile threads being created from within the C++ code.

Answer (score 27):

From [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v6rxmx/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.pd.prof.doc.user/topics/t_thrdvw_view.htm):

> A contention occurs when a thread is
>   waiting for a resource that is not
>   readily available; it slows the
>   execution of your code, but can clear
>   up over time.
>
> A deadlock occurs when a thread is
>   waiting for a resource that a second
>   thread has locked, and the second
>   thread is waiting for a resource that
>   the first thread has locked. More than
>   two threads can be involved in a
>   deadlock. A deadlock never resolves
>   itself. It often causes the whole
>   application, or the part that is
>   experiencing the deadlock, to halt.

Comment: This also explains difference between thread Contention and Deadlock

Answer (score 4):

I think there should be some clarification from the OP on the background of the question - I can think of 2 answers (though I'm sure there are additions to this list):

1. if you are referring to the general "concept" of thread contention and how it can present itself in an application, I defer to @DavidSchwartz's detailed answer above.
2. There is also the '.NET CLR Locks and Threads:Total # of Contentions' Performance Counter.  As taken from PerfMon description for this counter, it is defined as:

   > This counter displays the total number of times threads in the CLR have attempted to acquire a managed lock unsuccessfully. Managed locks can be acquired in many ways; by the "lock" statement in C# or by  calling System.Monitor.Enter or by using MethodImplOptions.Synchronized custom attribute.

...and I'm sure others for other OS'es and application frameworks.

Answer (score 3):

To me contention is a competition between 2 or more threads over a shared resource. Resource can be a lock, a counter etc. Competition means "who gets it first". The more threads the more contention. The more frequent access to a resource the more contention.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 threads. Thread A and Thread B, you also have object C.

A is currently accessing object C, and has placed a lock on that object.
B needs to access object C, but cannot do so until A releases the lock on object C.

Answer (score 1):

Another word might be concurrency.  It is simply the idea of two or more threads trying to use the same resource.

Answer (score 0):

Thread contention is also affect by I/O operations. Example when a Thread waiting for file read it can consider as a contention. Use I/O completion ports as solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Lock contention takes place when a thread tries to acquire the lock to
>   an object which is already acquired by other thread*. Until the object
>   is released, the thread is blocked (in other words, it is in the
>   Waiting state). In some cases, this may lead to a so-called serial
>   execution which negatively affects application.

from [dotTrace documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/profiler/2016.1/Lock_Contention.html)

Answer (score 0):

> Imagine the following scenario. You are preparing for tomorrow's final
>   examine and feel a little hungry. So, you give your younger brother
>   ten bucks and ask him to buy a pizza for you. In this case, you are
>   the main thread and your brother is a child thread. Once your order is
>   given, both you and your brother are doing their job concurrently
>   (i.e., studying and buying a pizza). Now, we have two cases to
>   consider. First, your brother brings your pizza back and terminates
>   while you are studying. In this case, you can stop studying and enjoy
>   the pizza. Second, you finish your study early and sleep (i.e., your
>   assigned job for today - study for tomorrow's final exam - is done)
>   before the pizza is available. Of course, you cannot sleep; otherwise,
>   you won't have a chance to eat the pizza. What you are going to do is
>   to wait until your brother brings the pizza back.

As in the example, the two cases give meaning of rivalry.