# BlockingCollection is taking too much time to wake up

Tags: c#, multithreading, producer-consumer, blockingcollection

I have an issue when `BlockingCollection<MyItem>` is taking too much time to wake up from `.Take()` call.

The scenario is this:
I have a thread that pushing data to `BlockingCollection` very fast (actually in XUnit i did a `for` loop. I have a 3 `Task` that just sitting in `.Take()` call and waiting to items to be added. From output I can see that almost 200 items (up to 1 second or more) was added to collection before the first `Task` wake up and actually collect data from `BlockingCollection`.

I have multiple "buffers" based on `BlockingCollection` organized in pipe-line fashion and all of them suffer from too-much-time-waking on `.Take()` action.

I tried `.TryTake()` and `.GetConsumingEnumerable()` with the same results.

The idea that in the end of this pipeline I have a one threaded, slow function that process items one by one and it could take unknown time to process single item. <strike>I just need to make sure that 'item' passed from "buffer" to "buffer" very fast (as soon as it get inserted in the first "buffer")</strike>

I just need to make sure that start-up time (in `.Take()` or `.TryTake()` etc..) will happen close to time when item added to collection

Comment: Post complete, executable repro code. I suspect that you can't and will find the bug in the process.

Comment: @usr eee.... Where I should look for a bug ? in `.Take()` implementation ? I didn't say that application crash or something and I didn't say that it's `not working`' - it does work and everything passed, processed, etc... ok. I'm asking for design pattern for fast producer - slow consumer

Comment: How many active threads do you (try to) have?

Comment: @Jasper my point is that there is no obvious mistake you are making. It is necessary to look at the code to find the mistake.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Hmmm.. though question. Currently I see about 65 threads on `vs.executionengine.x86` (xunit test running app) - so I guess almost all of them are mine and I guess I need good half of them alive. I'm not sure how to answer....

Comment: Your requirement is strange... Why do you care about _from "buffer" to "buffer" very fast_ at all? That part shouldn't matter. And with too many threads on too few cores they'll just have to wait their turn.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Sorry - it was misleading -> I correct the question

Comment: What do you mean by `start-up` time?

Comment: 65 threads?!?! If you have many more threads alive than lets say the (number of cores) *(2~4) then you have a serious design issue!

Comment: @VMAtm - As I sad in the question. It taking tooo long for `BlockingCollection` to wake-up and actually understand that it does have items in collection and actually `.Take()` them. I'm pushing up to 200 items into collection just before the very first `.Take()` unblock and collect itme

Comment: @AK_ I don't know how many threads from there are mine and what are they status :( The number is just final include-all-from-everywhere number. I don't know how to understand it :(

Comment: Well i guess your issues are coming from thread contention and context switching. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970345/what-is-thread-contention

Comment: @AK_ I guess you right ! Please post it as answer to question so I could 'mark it as answer'

Comment: Perhaps threading is not the right solution in this situation. Something asynchronous based on Task<T> might be a better approach. Or, since you have a sequence of data that you want to react to immediately, why not consider using the Reactive Extensions for .NET (Rx)?

Comment: @TimLong You are right. My solution more and more mimic the Rx. I even derive from `IObservable<>` and `IObserver<>` because this is exactly the data-flow that I need but I'm still struggling to understand Rx and actually here I run into problem of creating the streams... May be you have a link to GitHub project that using Rx so I could learn a little bit more about it ?

Comment: @Jasper I'm not sure if this will help, but I have just pushed this today... https://bitbucket.org/tigranetworks/ta.ascom.reactivecommunications