# Armadillo C++: How to make effcient assignment to submat

Tags: c++, armadillo

I want to assign the value of a matrix to the submat of another matrix as `A.submat(ni1, ni2, nk1, nk2) = B;` It seems very slow. I'm wondering why it's so slow, and is there some way to improve it?

Here is my testing codes(Because the function "XForwarDifference" need to be called millions time in my project, I need to profile it better)

```
#include <armadillo>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
using ms = std::chrono::milliseconds;
using ns = std::chrono::nanoseconds;
using get_time = std::chrono::steady_clock;

namespace {
  const arma::ivec::fixed<5> iforward = {-1, 0, 1, 2, 3};
  const double MCA_1 = -0.30874;
  const double MCA0 = -0.6326;
  const double MCA1 = 1.2330;
  const double MCA2 = -0.3334;
  const double MCA3 = 0.04168;
}

arma::mat XForwardDifference(arma::mat& mat,
                             const int& ni1,
                             const int& ni2,
                             const int& nk1,
                             const int& nk2,
                             const double& dx)
{
  arma::mat ret(size(mat));
  double sign_dx = 1./dx;
  double mca_1= sign_dx * MCA_1;
  double mca0 = sign_dx * MCA0;
  double mca1 = sign_dx * MCA1;
  double mca2 = sign_dx * MCA2;
  double mca3 = sign_dx * MCA3;
  auto t1 = get_time::now();
  auto m1 = mat.submat(ni1+iforward(0), nk1, ni2+iforward(0), nk2);
  auto t2 = get_time::now();
  auto m2 = mca_1 * m1;
  auto t3 = get_time::now();
  auto m3 = m2 + m2;
  auto t4 = get_time::now();
  mat.submat(ni1, nk1, ni2, nk2) = m3;
  auto t5 = get_time::now();
  std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<ns>(t2-t1).count() << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<ns>(t3-t2).count() << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<ns>(t4-t3).count() << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<ns>(t5-t4).count() << std::endl;


  // ret.submat(ni1, nk1, ni2, nk2) =
  //   mca_1* mat.submat(ni1+iforward(0), nk1, ni2+iforward(0), nk2) +
  //   mca0 * mat.submat(ni1+iforward(1), nk1, ni2+iforward(1), nk2) +
  //   mca1 * mat.submat(ni1+iforward(2), nk1, ni2+iforward(2), nk2) +
  //   mca2 * mat.submat(ni1+iforward(3), nk1, ni2+iforward(3), nk2) +
  //   mca3 * mat.submat(ni1+iforward(4), nk1, ni2+iforward(4), nk2);
  return ret;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  const int len = 3;
  int ni1, ni2, nk1, nk2, ni, nk;
  ni = 200;
  nk = 200;
  ni1 = len;
  ni2 = ni1 + ni - 1;
  nk1 = len;
  nk2 = nk1 + nk - 1;
  const double dx = 1.;
  auto start_time = get_time::now();
  arma::mat mat(ni + 2*len, nk + 2*len);
  mat = XForwardDifference(mat, ni1, ni2, nk1, nk2, dx);
  auto end_time = get_time::now();
  auto diff = end_time - start_time;
  std::cout << "Elapsed time is : "
            << std::chrono::duration_cast<ns>(diff).count()
            << " ns "
            << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
180
116
110
851123
Elapsed time is : 961975 ns
```

You can see `mat.submat(ni1, nk1, ni2, nk2) = m3;` covers the most of elapsed time.

hbrerkere gives the reason:

> Armadillo queues up all the operations until the result is assigned to a matrix or a submatrix. This is why the assignment to submat seems to take longer. It's actually doing the multiplication and addition at assignment time, not before. Also, don't use the auto keyword with Armadillo matrices and expressions, as that can lead to problems. – hbrerkere

```
  auto t1 = get_time::now();
  arma::mat m1 = mat.submat(ni1+iforward(0), nk1, ni2+iforward(0), nk2);
  auto t2 = get_time::now();
  arma::mat m2 = mca_1 * m1;
  auto t3 = get_time::now();
  arma::mat m3 = m2 + m2;
  auto t4 = get_time::now();
  ret = m3;
  auto t5 = get_time::now();
```

If I modify the codes as he said, then the output now is below:

```
391880
356480
373072
113051
Elapsed time is : 1352013 ns
```

I also encounter the situation that `auto` will bring problems in armadillo.

```
auto m1 = mat.submat(ni1, nk1, ni2, nk2) * 2;
cout << size(m1) << endl;
```

It will print very large size that is not correct.

Comment: Armadillo queues up all the operations until the result is assigned to a matrix or a submatrix. This is why the assignment to submat seems to take longer. It's actually doing the multiplication and addition at assignment time, not before.
Also, don't use the _auto_ keyword with Armadillo matrices and expressions, as that can lead to problems.

Comment: @hbrerkere Your answer is very helpful to me. If I use `arma::mat` instead of `auto`, the cost time is changed as you said.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be specific points in your code that should make it slow. What you're doing looks fine. The only thing I would suggest is that you should try to minimize the number of `submat` calls, as it's considered relatively expensive because it could be creating a temporary matrix. Consider doing the math you want to do without `submat`. Just calculate the indices and assign them yourself.

Given that, I have two other suggestions:

1. If you insist there might be something wrong with your code or something to improve, study alternative ways to writing it (if possible) and use a [function profiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)), such as Valgrind, to see what functions cost the most, and whether that can be optimized.
2. If you give up on that, consider learning how to do multithreading with C++. Nowadays, it's very easy. Either use [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP), which is super-easy... but you have to do it right as it's easy to do mistakes there (like [high contention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970345/what-is-thread-contention)); or use [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread), which is a relatively new C++ construct that will simply run a function in a thread. For your case, since your application is repetivive, you can make use of any of them. You can use [my simple thread pool](https://git.afach.de/samerafach/StdThreadPool) implementation, which will schedule calls of a new instance as soon as one is finished.

Good luck.